# Denied entry at Montenegro border. What are my options?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, denial-of-entry, montenegro

I am from India and I am studying in Cyprus for last 4 years. As I like to travel, so I came to Serbia. I planned to go to Montenegro for 2 days from there as my return flight to Cyprus was after 2 days. I had valid Cyrups card and at border I asked immigration if I could travel to Montenegro with Cyprus valid visa. They didn't reply but took my passport and put No entry stamp (c) type C. I accept my mistake but I didn't know that I can't travel with Cyprus card.
Will this affect my future travel? What is the solution and how get visa for Montenegro again? And after that can I apply for Schengen visa?

Answer (score 2):

Indians need a Visa to travel to Montenegro. I guess you already figured that one out. Generally it is advised to get that at the montenegrin (or serbian actually) embassy in India. If you are in Cyprus, which I expect you to be, there is a Consulate in Nicosia at :

13 Karaiskaki
3032 Limassol
Cyprus

A not entry stamp does look a bit bad and if you are ever asked if you were once denied entry into a country you have to answer yes. It will however most likely not be a problem when you enter as you did not commit a crime or anything similar, but the consular officer will decide that.

Comment: This is especially true if you have a later dated visa and entry stamp.

Comment: I just want to emphasise the word **ever**. Immigration authorities have long memories, so whilst it is natural to want to forget about it and move on, OP should be careful to disclose it whenever asked in those terms. If they meant 'in the last ten years', they would say so.